# Deterministic Multiplayer RTS game questions?

Tags: multiplayer, rts, floating-point

I am working on a cross-platform multiplayer RTS game where the different clients and a server(flash and C#), all need to stay **deterministically synchronised**.

To deal with Floatpoint inconsistencies, I've come across this method: http://joshblog.net/2007/01/30/flash-floating-point-number-errors/#comment-49912 which basically truncates off the nondeterministic part:

```
return Math.round(1000 * float) / 1000;
```

Howewer my concern is that every time there is a division, there is further chance of creating additional floatpoint errors, in essence making it worse?

.

So it occured to me, how about something like this:

```
function floatSafe(number:Number) : Number 
{return Math.round(float* 1024) / 1024; }
```

- ie **dividing with only powers of 2** ? What do you think?

.

Ironically with the above method I got less accurate results:

```
trace(  floatSafe(3/5) ) // 0.599609375
```

where as with the other method(dividing with 1000), or just tracing the raw value I am getting **3/5 = 0.6**

or Maybe thats what 3/5 actually is, IE 0.6 cannot really be represented with a floatpoint datatype, and would be more consistent across different platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point isn't "non-deterministic". There's no randomness. The floating point value of 1/10 will always be greater than the actual value of 1/10, not just some of the time. The rules are predictable - it's just sometimes hard to know which rules it is using.

Anyway, rounding the value is not guaranteed to work, even if accumulated error wasn't a problem. Any individual error introduced (where error can be defined as a result different from a hypothetical baseline) could make the difference between a value rounding up or a value rounding down, so the rounding operation itself could produce different results on different machines. So basically you eliminate something like 99.9% of your inaccuracies in exchange for getting a much larger inaccuracy 0.1% of the time.

A better idea is to use something truly deterministic, such as fixed point arithmetic, or to set the processor's floating point rules (which may not be possible on your platform).

Comment: There would not be any accumulated errors, as the game is built on all integer maths. However in some very rare instances a Float is required, and in those cases I would like to 'sanitize' those floats as much as possible.
so wouldn't the division by 1024 solve this problem? as that is on the power of 2, which I hope would make it consistent how the different platforms(C# and Flash) and different computers perform that operation?

Comment: Either you are exchanging data based on floats or you're not - if you are not, it's completely safe and you don't have to sanitise anything. If you are, it's completely unsafe and the fact that most of it is done with integers doesn't help. It doesn't matter what you round with or to - the wrong information is already in the value and multiplying it makes it worse.

Comment: Hold on, but float 'errors' are very small,  for example 0.9990000000000001 instead of 0.999.  So if you truncate/clip away the '0000000000001' , then the remaining 3 decimals should always be the same. Provided that the rounding process does not introduce additional 'errors'. And hence the idea of dividing by the powers of 2, which would improve the consistency? Or maybe I got the wrong end of the stick?

Comment: That logic assumes that all errors are positive biases. What happens if you truncate 0.99999999999999 and 1.0000000000000?

Comment: What "rare instances" require floating point numbers?  If we can design around those instances then your original problem is solved, and without trickery.

Comment: Both 0.9990000000000001 and 0.9989999999999999 get rounded to 0.999 with  Math.round(1000 * float) / 1000 ?

Comment: I mean I appreciate that you are trying to help, but really it appears you havent understood my question in my OP.
both negative and positive epsilons, IE 0.99999999999999 or 1.00000000000001 will get corrected to the same result = 1, with both of the rounding methods I've given!

My question was that: if I divide with 1000, am I introducing additional problems? and if **by making the division with 1024(a power of 2) I could avoid that?**

Comment: The point is that rounding does not solve your problem, even if you do it by a number that doesn't introduce extra error. Any rounding (or truncation/flooring) operation has 2 adjacent values where one will round up and one will round down. And if your error is large enough so that a number falls on the wrong side of that threshold, no operation can fix it as the information is already lost. The problem needs fixing before you get to this point.

Comment: "**if your error is large enough so that a number falls on the wrong side**"
- Yes but thats the whole point of the rounding method that the epsilon is always much smaller than what would affect 3-4 decimals, so if you round to that precision the inconsistency will disappear.
- my question does not concern that. My question is about if by the process of rounding to 3-4 decimals am I introducing additional problems, and if the powers of 2 thing would fix  that?

Comment: You are assuming your error is only ever equal to the epsilon. That implies you have not performed any operations whatsoever on the floating point value, and therefore you could just use a string. If, however, you are performing calculations with the float, then the error is likely to be larger than that, and rounding can make the error larger. It doesn't matter whether you use a power of two or not - you can make the error larger by rounding because any value with an error in it could be the wrong side of whatever threshold you round to.

Comment: If you're just interested in the effects of dividing a float by a power of two compared to some other number, then you might lose less precision that way, but the very act of multiplication and division loses precision because significant bits get shunted off at each end. The bigger the multiplior or divisor, the more bits you lose.

Comment: "**That implies you have not performed any operations whatsoever on the floating point value**"
- thats precisely what I've said before: there would not be accumulated errors, as the game is all integers, and any time a Float is used it is immediately subjected to this 'sanitizing' treatment. As a result the assumption that the error cannot be greater than epsilon is not an assumption but a fact.

Comment: And yes I am interested about the effects of dividing a float by a power of two compared to a non-power of 2, but I am only interested in if this would make it more **deterministically consistent** across platforms and i dont care about precision!! (I am perfectly happy with 3-4 decimals)

Comment: The amount of error on a floating point value is absolutely not guaranteed to be equal to some arbitrary epsilon value, even if you only perform one operation. And you can't be performing -all- your operations as integers because then you wouldn't have any floating point values to store. And no rounding method can guarantee to round 2 unknown values to the same result. What you want to do can't be done the way that you want to do it.

Comment: The magnitude of error on floating point values vary, but without exception ALL specification CPUs on ALL systems will always be less than what would affect 3-4 decimals after rounding with the method I posted in in my OP. This is a fact, and this was not even the question.
I am asking a **simple question of if dividing by the power of 2 would make it more consistent across platforms**, and for some reason you always seem to ignore this.

Comment: That first sentence is wrong, and I suggest you look into how floating point values are represented. A floating point value can be literally thousands away from the integer it tries to represent. But as I did mention above, "If you're just interested in the effects of dividing a float by a power of two compared to some other number, then you might lose less precision that way, but the very act of multiplication and division loses precision because significant bits get shunted off at each end." The approach may be less broken as it's a straight binary shift, but it's still broken.

Comment: **"approach may be less broken as it's a straight binary shift, but it's still broken"**
I will take that as a Yes, Thanks!
(in Flash fixed point math is not possible, and nor is pure integer only implementation, as internally all integer calculations are performed via floats, so I am looking for simply the **least bad** solution here)

Answer (score 0):

A value like 0.99900000000000000001 is there because the float cannot represent the original number at all not because the actual operation wasn't correct.

http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

That is a the IEEE standard just to give you a reason why rounding wont work. This doesn't mean all CPUs use this format.

I think people serialize their floating point numbers to a standard format over wire and remake the float on the other end, but I'm not entirely sure. You could try doing something like LISP programming langauge and find the value as a "x/y" then send x and y to the client and have him perform "x/y" to get the float.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I am aware of that, however as the OP explained, a consistency required which is cross platform ( Flash/C# )and cross system ( PC/Mac/Server). The solution is to use a float which is altogether less precise, IE only have 3-4 decimals. And my question concerned is that if by the act of rounding to 3 decimals, am I exposing myself to extra errors when I divide by 1000, and if it would be better to divide by 1024 ( as that is the powers of 2 )